Manage M365 Mailbox via .NET Console App with multi AD tenant fails to get remote PowerShell Session ID

I have a VM (Named DCVM-01) on Azure which is used a Domain Controller and have Active Directory
I have another VM (Named JBVM-01) on azure which is used to run IIS and is also having Exchange management tools

I am running a code via Visual Studio to get a Powershell session of DCVM-01 (Domain Controller) and then run PowerShell Snapin then work on Mailbox Maagement as it used to work with Microsoft Exchange.

Note: Currently my Email is on M365 not Microsoft Exchange, and I am
trying to take support of Exchange management tools to using similar
PowerShell commands to manage remote mailbox on M365

The code Sequence is as this
// Create a runspace
            InitialSessionState initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState);   

            runspace.Open();

            // Create a PowerShell pipeline
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            // Construct the New-PSSession command
            ps.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
            ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", "YourRemoteComputer"); // Replace with your target computer
            ps.AddParameter("Credential", new PSCredential("Domain\\Username", "Password")); // Replace with valid credentials

            // Invoke the command and get the results
            Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();

            // Extract the session ID
            PSObject sessionObject = results[0];
            Guid sessionId = (Guid)sessionObject.BaseObject;

            // Import the session using Import-PSSession
            ps.Commands.Clear();
            ps.AddCommand("Import-PSSession");
            ps.AddParameter("Session", sessionId);
            ps.Invoke();   

Here we are expecting SessionID, but it is returning Runspace object
(Guid)sessionObject.BaseObject

How do I get Session ID, and get into remote session, post that execute below code.
ps.Commands.Clear();
 ps.AddCommand("Add-PSSnapin")
     .AddParameter("Name", "*recipientmanagement");
 ps.Invoke();

After that below code
 ps.AddCommand("Enable-RemoteMailbox");
            ps.AddParameter("Identity", "user@domain.com"); // Replace with the user's email address
            ps.AddParameter("RemoteRoutingAddress", "user@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"); // Replace with the remote routing address

I am using .NET Core, C# Console app, to build this utility.

Important:  Same commands if I run directly from PowerShell, it works,
but if I try to translate it to C#, it fails.

$cred=get-credential
$Session= New-PSSession -computername DCVM-01.Domain.LOCAL -credential $cred  -Port 5985
 
Enter-PSSession $Session

Add-PSSnapin *receipientmanagement
Enable-RemoteMailbox

How do I run the above PowerShell code from C# Console App?
Update

As per the recommendation from Mathias R. Jessen https://stackoverflow.com/a/78871054/942855  when I do the following
PSObject sessionObject = results[0];
ps.AddCommand("Import-PSSession").AddParameter("Session", sessionObject);
ps.Invoke();

It throughs error at last line

Files cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. Provide a valid certificate with which to sign the files.

Update

I further made progress to Import-PSSession and Add-PSSnapin work by adding below line of code.
initialSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned;

Now I am stuck with MailBox commands
// Enable Remote Mailbox
 ps.Commands.Clear();
 ps.AddCommand("Enable-RemoteMailbox");
 ps.AddParameter("Identity", "SamAccountName"); 
 ps.AddParameter("RemoteRoutingAddress", "SamAccountName@XXXXX.mail.protection.outlook.com");  
 ps.Invoke()

Above code throws error as below
The term 'Enable-RemoteMailbox' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Note: This Enable-RemoteMailbox works directly from PowerShell but from Visual Studio it fails with above error.
Update

Ran the command Get-Command -Noun *RemoteMailbox on powershell
on target server DCVM-01 nothing is shown (as expected because there is no exchange management tools installed here.)
on source server JBVM-01 this is what I see



Here we are expecting SessionID, but it is returning Runspace object

You should be expecting an object of type PSSession - because that's what New-PSSession outputs.
Since Import-PSSession's -Session parameter already accepts objects of that type, simply pass it directly:
ps.AddCommand("Import-PSSession").AddParameter("Session", sessionObject);


With this, it throws the following error
Files cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. Provide a valid certificate with which to sign the files.

Updated my question with the error

@HaBo That means you need to update the execution policy on the machine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.4

On the target server (DC Box)?

@HaBo On the system where you execute the code - so if you're hosting this in a web app on JBVM-01, then JBVM-01 needs to have its execution policy reconfigured

So I ran this Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned on the IIS (Source Box) still same error

Made progress by adding initialSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned; now stuck with Enable-RemoteMailbox, it says command is not recognized

@HaBo is that after executing Import-PSSession? The remote session might add a noun prefix, try Get-Command -Noun *RemoteMailbox to discover the actual command names

Yes it is in this sequence New-PSSession, Import-PSSession, Add-PSSnapin than Enable-RemoteMailbox and it fails at Enable-RemoteMailbox with unknown command Enable-RemoteMailbox
